# system error 126 when connecting DocumentDB in PowerBI Desktop

Tags: amazon-web-services, odbc, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to connect DocumentDB to PowerBI using `amazon-documentdb-odbc-driver`, link to repo [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-documentdb-odbc-driver).

I installed connector using `documentdb-odbc-amd64-1.0.0-all.exe` . I followed [AWS instuctions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-odbc-setup-windows.html) and I got `Connection succeeded` when I added DocumentDB DSN to system DNS.

However I am getting the following error whe trying to connect to my database in PowerBI:

```
Unable to connect

Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 126. The specified module could not be found
Amazon DocumentDB, C:\Program Files\Amazon DocumentDB\ODBC Driver\documentdb.odbc.dll
```

**Question**

I cannot find any information on how to fix this issue. I found information that this error means that the ODBC driver itself (DLL file) cannot load its dependency files but I am not sure how to connect DocumentDB to PowerBI without this connector.

I would be grateful on how to solve this issue or what are the other ways to connect DocumentDB to PowerBI.

Comment: I got the same error on my machine but not on another machine where I was able to get it to work. The only difference was that on my machine I installed the 32 bit driver first by mistake, uninstalled it and then installed the 64bit driver. On the other machine I just installed the 64 bit driver. Other difference is that my machine is Windows 11 whereas the other one was Windows server 2022